# order by random

Tags: sqlite

How can I use in SQLite, "order by random()" only if row count of table = 245?

I need to use this `SELECT * FROM generic table ORDER BY RANDOM();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
select * from generictable 
  order by case when ((select count(*) from generictable) = 245) then random()
else 1 end
```